# I want to know the last index of a regex match in python's re lib

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
a = re.compile('myregex')
a.search(target_string)
```

I'm looking for a way to get the index of the next char after a possible match.

I know you can get the last position of a group but if my regex consists of something more than a group I'd like to get that or do I need to start counting my regex string chars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MatchObject` returned by `.search()` has a [`.end()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.end); by default it returns the end position for which your *whole* regular expression matched.

You can also pass the method a group to find the end point of for that specific group, with the `0` group being the whole pattern.

Demonstration:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = re.compile('(my|your) regex')
>>> match = a.search('Somewhere in this string is my regex; not much different from your regex.')
>>> print match.end()
36
>>> print match.end(1)
30
```